# What is difference between .edmx and .dbml file in linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What is difference between .edmx and .dbml file in linq?In VS 2008 which datasource is best choice where edmx or dbml?Any problem will arise using edmx file in VS 2008?Can i use edmx in VS-2008?

Comment: You should award someone

Answer (score 44):

**edmx** is the modeling file for **Entity Framework**.

**dbml** is the modeling file for **Linq 2 Sql**.

You should spend your time learning Entity Framework as Linq 2 Sql is deprecated.

Comment: He should definitely learn EF, but L2S is not deprecated. Furthermore if he is using VS2008 (.NET<4) EF is just plain awful and unoptimized for MSSQL usage in comparison to L2S. Not everyone needs or should use EF, specialized tools are sometimes better than general-purpose ones.

Comment: Maybe it's not officially deprecated, but it should definitely be treated as such as the development has been shut down (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx). But EF prior to EF4 is not that fun, that's true. IMO L2S is working for simple projects, but should be avoided if it's a long term project (I am working with L2S now and I feel the pain)

Comment: Nope, not dead and definitely receiving new features, its even been discussed here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041011/is-linq-to-sql-deprecated). It just does not receive that much focus, but then again it doesn't need that much attention as it's a well rounded functional toolset. Sadly, most people don't even use EF functionality not in L2S and treat EF as L2S while putting up with performance penalties that abstraction inevitably brings. Blindly rushing to things just because of "novelty factor" is IMHO not a good thing, especially if you don't need them

Comment: That is interesting. I just blindly believed Rob Conery in his EF videos on Tekpub. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks dudes your comments are valuable for me to choose which framework is best  based on project type and value.thank for spending your valuable time for suggestion.

Comment: I prefer NHibernate than EF. It is worth a try.

Answer (score 36):

`.edmx` is the Entity Framework. `.dbml` is LINQ-to-SQL. While their general purpose is the same, they are entirely different frameworks. Entity Framework is newer and will probably be the best investment of your time to learn since I suspect that is where a lot of innovation is going to go.

Answer (score 17):

Both are introduced as latest technologies and at times a bit confusing when to use which. Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL have a lot in common but still different from each other in quite a few ways:

Entity Framework:
1. Enterprise Development:
2. Works with Conceptual model of database:
3. Works with all data sources:
4. ".EDMX" is created while using Entity Framework:

LINQ::
1. Rapid Application Development:
2. Works with objects in database:
3. Mainly woks with SQL Server:
4. ".dbml" is created while using LINQ to SQL:
:

Entity Framework is more targeted towards Enterprise Development where the schema is usually optimized for storage considerations like performance consistency and partitioning. Entity Framework is designed around exposing an application-oriented data model that is loosely coupled and may differ from the existing database schema. For example, you can map a single entity (class) to multiple or map multiple entities to the same table. Entity Framework has “.edmx” (ADO.NET Entity Model) file when added in the application.

LINQ to SQL mainly has features to support Rapid Application Development against SQL Server. LINQ to SQL allows you to have a strongly typed view of your existing database schema. You can build LINQ queries over tables and return results as strong typed objects. LINQ to SQL has “.dbml”(LINQ to SQL) file when added in the application. You can use LINQ to SQL by decorating the existing classes with the attributes.

[Original source: [https://parassanghani.blogspot.com/2011/01/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql.html]](https://parassanghani.blogspot.com/2011/01/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql.html)

Comment: Nice copy/paste!  http://parassanghani.blogspot.com/2011/01/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql.html

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL mainly has features to support Rapid Application Development against SQL Server. LINQ to SQL allows you to have a strongly typed view of your existing database schema. You can build LINQ queries over tables and return results as strong typed objects. LINQ to SQL has “.dbml”(LINQ to SQL) file when added in the application. You can use LINQ to SQL by decorating the existing classes with the attributes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, which was specifically about the files in question. It was not asking for a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I never understood the literature like definitions. Anyways the bottom line is L2S is lightweight and EF is heavy weight. Meaning L2S works only with SQLServer and EF works with many more.

Reference: [Difference between L2S and EF](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/difference-between-linq-to-sql-and-entity-framework)