# linq to sql for CRUD framework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, frameworks

may i know is there any good Linq to Sql C# framework available out there?
I found these below but it seem to be too complex. Could you advice?

1) http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/

Comment: If your objectives are simple LinqToSql **IS** your framework, you just use the repository pattern over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Linq to SQL is deprecated by MS. If you want to stick with MS Frameworks take a look at Entity Framework.</strike> (See comments)

I would advice to use NHibernate. If you use their fluent configuration or even auto configuration you can easily build a simple system. As soon as you need something more sophisticated NHibernate has the power you need.

Of course this won't be the simplest way to do CURD, however database access is no simple topic and should need some thought.

You can google for active record implementations for .net if you want to take the ruby on rails approach, which is quite pragmatic and elegant, too.

Edit to provide you with a sample take a look at the NH getting started guide: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx

It's relatively easy to get going with NHibernate. As you require more sophisticated features you can drill deeper into the framework.

Notice that the getting started guide uses XML Mapping Configuration. You can use http://fluentnhibernate.org/ to fluently configure your mappings like:

```
public class SomeTypeMap : ClassMap<SomeType>
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Property1);
    Map(x => x.Property2);
    // ....
    Map(x => x.PropertyN);
}
```

The fluent interface exposes all further functions chained on the Map() method.

Fluent NH even provides Auto Mapping: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

Comment: Seem like i need to take a look at the linq to NHibernate.. it is completely new to me.

Comment: @Zebi: Could you provide me a good sample code on NHibernate?

Comment: We are still using NHibernate 2.x + linq2nhibernate however I think NH 3.0 already includes build in linq support.

Comment: @Zebi: Can this NHibernate use in both window app and web? When u say  NH 3.0 build in linq support, do u meant that only NH 3.0 can write linq code?

Comment: You can use NHibernate in web and desktop apps. The session object exposes a Query<T> method to start queries like session.Query<SomeType>().Where(x => x.Property1 == "someValue").ToList();

Comment: @Zebi: I read through the http://nhforge.org/ and it seems that it is famous and there are many people using it. Downloading now... :) Let me test it out

Comment: @Zebi: You did say `it won't be the simplest way to do CURD`, can you explain more? Do u meant i need more effort to do the CRUD? Could this be as simple as what i did for linq to sql?

Comment: I'd like to see the link to a press release that says LINQ to SQL is deprecated. This kind of FUD was spread around before and later debunked. Have a look at a SO thread about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041011/is-linq-to-sql-deprecated

Comment: @belinq: NHibernate brings you much much more than pure CRUD functionality. Doing simple CRUD with NHibernate is not hard. If you want to use the advanced concepts of NHibernate you will have to invest some work. However this will be the case, too if you take an other solution (or you will hit the wall because advanced concepts are not covered). NHibernate is used since years by many people and therefore is a very solid piece of software.

Comment: @Frank: thanks for the link, thats new to me. However the intend seems still to merge Link2Sql and EntityFramework. I edited my post.

Comment: @Frank http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. "We are listening to customers regarding LINQ to SQL and will continue to evolve the product based on feedback we receive from the community as well." - It not being the preferred choice (over EF) is still okay but L2S is still very much alive. Can one of you link me to a review that contrasts both L2S and EF and comments on the benefits that EF provides?