# Compile-time SQL statement syntax checking?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, orm

Question:

What's currently the best leightweight option for compile-time SQL statement syntax checking in C#/VB.NET ?

Basically, what I want is to create a select/update/insert/delete statement in code, so I can have compile-time checking (whether all columns exists and have the right name etc.).

**Note:** 
It should be leightweight. I don't really want a fully fledged ORM like nHibernate or EF, and no deprecated framework like LINQ to SQL, and neither must it work on multiple databases (not that it would be a disadvantage).
What I want is to let a program run over my database, that creates a class for all tables and views (like some tools for nhibernate), and then accessing the class fields instead of writing a string, in order to catch errors at compile time instead of runtime.

What I don't want is having to map things manually in XML, or a heavy-weight like nHibernate that is slow because it does a lot of additional things that I don't really need.

So far, the only things I found is Indy.Data and C-Omega from this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10665/Extending-C-to-Support-SQL-Syntax-at-Compile-Time

Comment: LINQ to SQL isn't deprecated, as far as I'm aware... EF is the preferred solution, but LINQ to SQL isn't actually deprecated.

Comment: LINQ to SQL is not deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3041035/7426

Comment: AFAIK it WAS deprecated, then MS backed down.