# Using Linq to SQL in asp.net 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core-mvc

Can I use Linq to SQL in asp.net 5 mvc 6?

There is no "Linq to SQL Classes" in "Add New Item" form
[image]

I know its not supported in dot net core 5 but I don't need dnx core 5 and cross platform feature. I'm ok with dnx core 4.5.1

How can I add Linq to SQL Classes file (.dbml) to MVC 6 Project?

Comment: There is no error. I just can't find "Linq to SQL Classes" in "Add New Item Page". What is wrong? Screenshot added.

Comment: Probably because `LINQ to SQL` has been depricated ages ago. You will need to look into using Entity Framework going forwards, if you want to use a Microsoft supported ORM. [Is LINQ to SQL deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041011/is-linq-to-sql-deprecated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add Linq To SQL Classes file, you have to add Class Library project to your solution. Now you can add Linq to SQL Classes (.dbml file) to this project.

Then add reference to this Class Library from your main project.

NOTE: you can not use dnxcore 5 in this way. Your main project should use dnx 4.5.1 and class library should use dotNet framework 4.5.1 as target framework.

[image: Using linq to SQL in asp.net 5 mvc 6]

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, in VS just go to Tools - Get tools and features - Individual components - Select LINQ to SQL tools and then click on Modify.