# Asp.Net 5 missing Linq to Sql class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

How can I add a Linq to Sql file in Microsoft **Asp.Net 5 with Mvc 6**.
see the screenshot below. There is no way where I can find this Linq to Sql file.
As well there is no C# tab at the side??

[image]

When I open the project on Asp.Net 4 with Mvc 5 there is this C# tab, as well as the Linq to sql file.

Comment: Are you sure Linq to SQL is a good choice for new project in 2016?

Comment: Should I consider using EF 7?

Comment: EF7 looks very promising, but it's still not released. You can check their [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap). Choosing ORM is an interesting question and it really depends on your application needs. I think you can google for some comparisons between ORM's.

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov to be fair, neither is aspnet5.  Both are RC1 and 'supported`. I'd agree that as LINQ to SQL's been pretty unloved my MS since 2008 that it wouldn't be on my list to use in a new project.

Comment: The problem of EF7 is that basic features like Lazy Loading will not be a part of Release #1.

Comment: This was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516188/using-linq-to-sql-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)

Comment: No that doesn't work

Comment: What .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting 4.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33584832/1284637), however I've tried to add more step by step instructions so that it could help you and others.

Right click on `src` and Add > New Project. Select `Class Libarary`. Take note of the .NET Framework (I'm using 4.6 here), as you will have to match that with your main project.

[image: Add new project]

The class library should appear in your solution.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Right click on the class library *(or a sub folder where you want the Linq To Sql Classes)*, and Add > New Item. In the data tab (on the left), it should have the item `LINQ to SQL Classes`

[image: Add Linq To Sql Classes]

Configure your LINQ to SQL.

[image: LINQ to SQL]

In your main asp.net-5 web application, make sure your project.json is setup so that it's using the **same .NET Framework** as your Class Library (check first step). I'm using 4.6 here.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {
    }
},
```

Still in your main asp.net-5 solution, right click on References > Add Reference.

[image: Add Reference]

Add the Class Library reference.

[image: Reference]

I hope this helps.

Comment: No connection string named 'NORTHWNDEntities' could be found in the application config file. error occurred when binding the mentioned way.i'm using entity.

Comment: It cannot find the connection string, so you will have to set it up properly in your application.json file.

`"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=YOURDB;integrated security=true;Trusted_Connection=True;Persist Security Info=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }`

and in your startup.cs file (after loading your appsettings.json) you can reference its like so:

`Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])` 

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i tried, but it can't work. can you please share any document link.

Comment: I'm not sure what you problem is and there's not enough information to go on. Please ask the question on stackoverflow with your setup and I'll answer it.

Comment: LINQ to SQL is still not listed. It is now 2017 and I am using VS2017. What the hell are they thinking? EF is slow and heavy. If I want business logic I'll put it in the middle tier ie in the web service implementation.

Comment: You have to add it manually. http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Enabling-LINQ-to-SQL-in-Visual-Studio-2017