# .NET Core - Targetting old .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

What I want to do: use an older project (.NET 3.5) data context and repositories in a .net core application (targetting .net 4.5). I put a more detailed explanation and what I tried below.

**What I want to do**

I am building a MVC application using .NET Core (on .NET 4.6 framework) at my work. The application needs to integrate with an existing database.

Normally in my .NET Core MVC applications, in `startup.cs` I do something like:

`services.DbContext<Context>(options...)` and parse a connection string. I then do `services.AddTransient`... and inject a repository to my controllers, which lets me access the database.

However, instead of setting up my own database context and repositories and queries, I would like to use the existing codebase at my work. I created my project in the same solution as the existing ones. The existing projects are web forms, and use .NET 3.5. The way they do the database and repositories is a bit different - it uses `DataContext` in `System.Data.Linq`, and reads a connection string from `web.config`. Instead of dependency injection, then, the controllers just instantiate an instance of this class.

**What I have tried**

In my `startup.cs`, I tried to create a DataContext and parse it into the other project's repository, but it said something like `You need to reference` System.Data.Linq `in the .NET framework 3.5.0`.

Is it possible for a .NET Core project targeting .NET 4.5, to use data context classes and repositories built using .NET 3.5?

Comment: I would build two projects.  One as a class project using Net 3.5 for old code.  Then create a main project with Net 4.5 which references the class project.

Comment: hi @jdweng - that's the current set up, actually. So the old project (which is not the startup project) that uses 3.5, requires a datacontext to be initialized, which I do not think exists in the same for in .net 4.5. I tried to create one in the same way the .net 3.5 project does, then pass it to the older project's repositories, but where I initialize it in the .net 4.5 project became red and threw errors, asking me to include something from `system.data.linq`, which exists in .net 3.5 but doesnt seem to be present any  in .net 4.5. So that is the problem I am wrestling with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830033/asp-net-5-missing-linq-to-sql-class Once you have done that you can wrapper those objects into usable objects in your .net core application

Comment: Hi @yaWang, thanks for the link, I am not trying to add a linq to sql file, but use entire classes and data contexts from .net 3.5 in my .net 4.5 app. Thanks for the link though, although I don't think I will be able to wrap repositories and the such in a linq to sql file in the way that answer does.

Comment: Check in menu Project : Add Reference : Net. See if System.Data.Linq exists.  Microsoft sometimes obsoletes libraries but still makes them available.

Comment: @jweng ok thanks, will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my problem. I don't think I was clear enough. Here is what my solution is like:

Solution
  - .NET 3.5 project
  - .NET 4.5 project

I was creating a repository from .NET 3.5 project in my newer one, and it was creating a datacontext that looks for a `web.config` file. Even though I created one, it looks like it must try to find that `web.config` inside of the startup project, regardless of where the data context is created. I made one but it still didn't detect that, I'm not sure why.

I was able to go into the old project and modify the datacontext to directly received a connection string. However, this isn't ideal - I will look for a way to pass a connection string into the older project from my new one, which I think is a good solution.

@jwdeny was correct in saying I had to add a reference to System.Data.Linq. The project told me to add a reference to 3.5, but adding System.Data.Linq 4.0 was enough.